# LSTM Tensor shape and hyper parameters Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm learning how to use an LSTM RNN.
I saw this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeffmcG42SY&
After that, I tried to apply what I learned and to change the dataset.
The problem is, I'm kinda lost with all the reshapes and I don't really know how to use them and why they are here...
My dataset got 7 columns and 546 rows.
Here's my hyper parameters

```
# hyperparameters
lr = 0.001
training_iters = 100000
batch_size = 64

n_inputs = 7   # columns
n_steps = 546  # rows
n_hidden_units = 128   # neurons in hidden layer
n_classes = 1  # class
```

When I launch my session, it looks like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    step = 0
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_xs, batch_ys = inputX, inputY
        batch_xs = batch_xs.reshape([batch_size, n_steps, n_inputs])
        sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={
            x: batch_xs,
            y: batch_ys,
        })
        if step % 20 == 0:
            print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={
            x: batch_xs,
            y: batch_ys,
            }))
        step += 1
```

Then, I have an error message

"cannot reshape array of size 3822 into shape (64,546,7)"

If anyone can explain me how that work and/or how to solve the problem, that would be really great !

Thank you

Comment: why don't you print your tensor shapes to see what are their dimensions?

Comment: The input should be `[batch_size,time_steps,sample_dim]`. In your dataset,  i assume each row has a sequence data of length 7. So pick N rows that will be your `batch_size`, `time_steps` is 7 and each sample if its `one-hot `encoded vector will be `sample_dim`

Comment: Well, my batch size are x: (546, 7) and y: (546, 1). My features aren't one hot, so if I understand, I won't have a sample dim parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LSTM Cell has input and the LSTM cell is unrolled over time for different inputs of one sequence. And since we use batch learning algorithms, we need to supply a batch of input. So the LSTM input in tesorflow is of shape (batch_size X time steps to unroll X input size).

In your case

1. batch_size = 64
2. times steps to unroll = 546
3. input size = 7

Base how you input is (how you did feature extraction), you will have to reshape it to 64 X 546 X 7 (== 244608) which ofcourse will fail if your input size is 3822

Think of LSTM from sequence to sequence predictions (one to one model). For example lets say you have a list of sentences (lets say S sentences). Lets say you have W words in each sentence. Now you want to predict the Parts of speech tag for each word in each sentence. Lets say you represent each word as a hot one encoding and your vocabulary size is V. So size of the hot one encoded vector will be V.

Now your LSTM model input shape will be (Batch size X W X V) where Batch size is << S and is normally 32 or 64.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand this better now !